# Simple Discrete Convolution Question

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

With the discrete step function

$$
  u[n] = \begin{cases}
  1, & n \ge 0 \\
  0, & n < 0 \\
  \end{cases}
$$

And the output $y[n]$ defined as a discrete convolution of the input $x[n]$ with the impulse response $h[n]$:

$$
  y[n] = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h[k] x[n-k]
$$

If the input is defined as:

$$
  x[n] = e^{j\omega n} u[n]
$$

What is the output?

My textbook says the answer is:

$$
  y[n] = \begin{cases}
    0, & n < 0 \\
    \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n h[k] e^{-j\omega k}\right) e^{j \omega n}, & n \ge 0 \\
  \end{cases}
$$

I don't see how the book arrives at this answer. My work is:

$$
  u[n-k] = \begin{cases}
  1, & n \ge k \\
  0, & n < k \\
  \end{cases}
$$

\begin{align*}
  y[n] &= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h[k] x[n-k] \\
  &= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h[k] e^{j\omega (n-k)} u[n-k] \\
  &= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{n} h[k] e^{j\omega (n-k)} \\
  &= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{n} h[k] e^{-j\omega k} e^{j\omega n} \\
\end{align*}

My work seems correct, but it clearly doesn't match the text answer. I see why the input is zero for $n < 0$, because $u[n]$ will be zero, but I don't see why the output will be zero for $n < 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations are indeed correct. However, the textbook answer is based on the assumption that the impulse response $h[k]$ is [causal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_filter) in that $h[k]=0$ for $k<0$ - otherwise the filter output $y[n]$ would be dependent on future values of the input $x[n]$.